# Log request in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I try to log all posted data in my WebApi when a exception is thrown. I have try this:

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (request.Content == null) 
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    var Body = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    request.Properties["body"] = Body;

    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

And in my error log method i get the posted values in `Properties["body"]`.

But when the users upload a image I get this when I try to get the files:

> This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked.
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files()

How can I store only posted `data(text)` in this property?

Comment: Why not use `Request.Form`?

Comment: There is no Request.Form in ApiController.